# Need Help Understanding R Code

Tags: r

I'm trying to find if (a) fewer than 62% or more than 74% of the sample means within one standard deviation of the expected value, or (b) fewer than 92% or more than 98% of the sample means within two standard deviations of the expected value.

Given that we have already set `mu` and `sigma`, and `Finv` is a quantile function. I was given the last two lines of code. Can someone please explain to me what they mean and what kind of output I should be getting? (Currently my only output is `0`)

```
n.iterations <- 100000
n <- 10
xbar <- numeric(n.iterations)

for (i in 1:n.iterations){
  x <- sapply(runif(n), Finv)
   xbar[i] <- mean(x)
 }


mean((mu-1*sigma/sqrt(n) <= xbar) & (xbar <= mu+1*sigma/sqrt(n)))

mean((mu-2*sigma/sqrt(n) <= xbar) & (xbar <= mu+2*sigma/sqrt(n)))
```

Comment: It seems to be related to some kind of confidence interval, and if `xbar` is or is not inside that confidence interval. Other than that, there are not enough details here that allows us to help you. In addition, if you are uncertain what the individual parts of the code do, reading the documentation for the different functions and operators is a good way to start.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra Question has been updated to add more details

Comment: Thanks for the update. These lines of code seem to do exactly what you want. What exactly is unclear? If it is related to the code, I think running each of the parts of the expression separately will help you understand what is going on.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra is it the mean of the xbars when the xbars are outside of 1 or 2 standard deviations of the mean (respectively)

Comment: What does `head(xbar)` give you? I'm not sure what you are doing with the Finv, are you supposed to be taking n.iterations random samples of size 10?  I think you have been given a shortcut way to do the problem but you need to understand the long way first.

Comment: @Elin `head(xbar)` gives me `0 0 0 0 0` which is making me think there is something wrong with the code, but I don't know what

Comment: @AmandaR. The two last lines takes the mean of a binary (TRUE/FALSE) vector, effectively returning the proportion of TRUEs. If you multiply by 100 you will get the percentage of cases that fall within the given intervals.

Comment: @AkselA 0=False, 1=True correct? So if I do `100*mean((mu-1*sigma/sqrt(n) <= xbar) & (xbar <= mu+1*sigma/sqrt(n)))` then I will get the percentage of cases that fall within the 1 standrd deviation of the mean?

Comment: @AmandaR. Correct

Comment: @AkselA So if I get `0` when I run the as a result of running the following code 'mean((mu-1*sigma/sqrt(n) <= xbar) & (xbar <= mu+1*sigma/sqrt(n)))` then that means that none of the sample means fall within one standard deviation of the true mean?

Comment: @AmandaR. Assuming you've set `mu` and `sigma` appropriately, yes it should. It might be a good idea to plot the values (say `hist(xbar)`), to get a rough feel of the distribution, and then see where mu ± sigma/sqrt(n) ends up within it. And by the way the interval you're calculating corresponds to one [standard error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error#Standard_error_of_the_mean)

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little bit puzzled by your question, because it askes about data "within standard deviation" but also asks about quantiles - which seems odd... and here is why

[image]

Consider the upper picture generated from the following code:

```
mymean <- 5
mysd   <- 2

curve(dnorm(x, mean = mymean, sd = mysd), from = -2, to = 12)
abline(v = mymean, col = "red", lwd = 2)

xtimessd = 1
abline(v = c(mymean - mysd*xtimessd, mymean + mysd*xtimessd), col = "blue", lwd = 1, lty = 2)
xtimessd = 2
abline(v = c(mymean - mysd*xtimessd, mymean + mysd*xtimessd), col = "cyan", lwd = 1, lty = 2)
xtimessd = 3
abline(v = c(mymean - mysd*xtimessd, mymean + mysd*xtimessd), col = "green", lwd = 1, lty = 2)

# 62th and 74th quantile
targetQunatiles <- qnorm(c(0.62, 0.75), mean = mymean, sd = mysd)
abline(v = targetQunatiles, col = "orange", lwd = 2, lty = 1)
```

Given your *population* mean and standard deviation the figure about shows the probability density function of a *normal distribution*.

The dotted lines are the "`xtimes` within sd" values. (There is really no magic, but it is related to the [68–95–99.7 rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule)).

On the other hand, if we look into the quantile function, i.e., in your example we are looking into values 62% and 74%, that can be computed by `qnorm`.

As you can see, based on your question "fewer than 62% or more than 74% of the sample means", you will exclude values between `5.610962` and `6.348980`.

So, still, from your question I don't know what you are asking about the relation between the statement of "within sd" and "looking for quantiles" as both are independen of each other.